# Delete a trendline if it bisects any candle bodies between pivot points

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am drawing trendlines between pivot points and that all works fine (highs to highs and lows to lows).

However, if that trendline bisects any candle bodies in-between the two adjacent high pivot points i want to delete the line.  I just cant understand why my code's not working....

```
    topPrc  = math.max(close,open)
    bottomPrc = math.min(close,open)
//xa, y1, xb, y2 were set earlier in code with my pivot points bit.  that all works.  it's below that doesnt
    line TL = line.new(xa,y1,xb,y2,xloc.bar_index,extend.right,trendlineColor,getLineStyle(trendlineStyle),trendlineWidth)
    array.push(lineArray,TL)
    //delete line if cuts candle bodies between pivots
    lastIndex = array.size(lineArray)-1
    //go through candles between pivots on that trendline
    for r = xa to xb by 1
      linePrice = line.get_price(TL,r)
      if linePrice < topPrc[r]
          line.delete(TL)
          array.pop(lineArray)
          break
```

I also repeat the delete code for if linePrice > bottomPrc[r], but i still see trendlines bisecting candle bodies between pivot points.....Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an offset by getting candles data instead of bar_index.
`topPrc[r]` - r here is the bar_index in your loop which of course checks the wrong candles for you.
`topPrc[bar_index - r]`

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean....